# ios make subview appear on top of CALayer

Tags: ios, calayer, addsubview

```
    [[background layer] addSublayer:myLayer];
    [background addSubview:toolbar];
```

I have a UIImageView called background. On top of this I have a subview called toolbar. Also, I have a CALayer on top of my background. The problem is, that I need toolbar to be on top of myLayer. How to make subview appear on top of layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the wrong way to do this is the zPosition property set to -1

Answer (score 1):

```
 [background bringSubviewToFront:toolbar];
```